# Dynamically set bounds on nearbySearch based on search critieria

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

We've implemented a search box and google maps on our page to allow customers to perform searches based on places queries, and so far it's working well.  However, using TextSearch we almost always get 20 results (unless it's a specific point).  What we prefer though, is to return a set of results that makes more sense to a user based on their search (i.e. if they're searching for churches within a zipcode, we shouldn't show churches outside the zip code).

I know we can bias our results based on location and radius, and even restrict results based on location / radius using NearbySearch.

However, our customers are national users who may be searching in any area in the world, so we're not sure, until the user searches, what location and radius to set as a restriction.  I'd like to determine that dynamically based on their query.

For example, in Google Maps if you search for "Churches near 30319" you get a much more localized result set than "Churches near Georgia"

Churches near 30319:
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=churches+near+30319&hl=en&sll=33.772251,-84.296934&sspn=0.049158,0.082312&hq=churches&hnear=Atlanta,+Georgia+30319&t=m&z=14

Churches near Georgia:
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=churches+near+Georgia&hl=en&sll=33.870438,-84.332304&sspn=0.049102,0.082312&hq=churches&hnear=Georgia&t=m&z=8

I've tested doing a separate query using geocode to get the single-point location of the query. i.e.

```
getGeneralVicinity = ->
  address = $('#address').val()
  window.oneq.geocode.geocoder.geocode
    address: address,
    (results, status) ->
      if status is google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK
        console.log(results[0].types)
```

It seems by possibly finding the type of the geocode result (i.e locality) we could determine a radius and use the geometry.location for the location bounds.  Unfortunately, it's not consistent, and if a user only searches for "churches", this doesn't give us the desired results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. I will refer to the Geocoding API as its JSON feed rather than the Google implementation of it, so detail will come straight from the source. There are some very interesting parameters that come back when geocoding something. Try it:

- Georgia: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=georgia&sensor=true
- 30319:http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=30319&sensor=true

Both of the second-tier address components are Georgia. However, there are a few differing parameters, and the one you want is `geometry`. This indicates the shape of the area.

Take, for example, the 30319 request. You will get as bounds:

```
"bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 33.9203610,
              "lng" : -84.30943599999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 33.83286890,
              "lng" : -84.35826589999999
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 33.87309460,
           "lng" : -84.33842899999999
        },
```

This tells you three things:

- The corners of the bounding box
- The centre of the box (which will be the intersection of the vertex lines)

This allows you to compute the maximum distance from your centre, which you can then feed back into your google places API search as radius. Conversion from lat/long to distance is trivial: it's called the orthodromic path. Two formulas exist - one for small distances ([Haversine's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)), the other for large distances ([this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)). Someone wrote a calculator for these: http://williams.best.vwh.net/gccalc.htm . You'll quickly see that the bounding box for 30319 spans 10km, whilst the georgia one spans almost 700 (which would require multiple Google Places requests to match).

Let me know if this wasn't clear and I'll elaborate further.

Comment: Hey Sebastien, thanks for the great feedback.  This is very close to what I'm looking for.  Are you suggesting I get "30319" or "Georgia" by doing a regex on their search?  My concern is that I don't exactly know what they are looking for.  (i.e. they could simply put "churches", or "churches near 30319" or "churches in Georgia", etc.).

Comment: What I'm suggesting is to isolate the center of their search using language processing. If they say ("X near Y"), geocode Y and base on this. Same with ("X in Y"), but int his case, you're absolutely bounding to the location specified. It should be very straightforward to implement.

Comment: Im hoping to accomplish this without language processing.  I've listed near and in, but there could be a variety of terms used.  Since Google Maps already has to accomplish this exact problem, I would've imagined they'd have an API that would do that heavy lifting

Comment: Not one that is accessible, sadly. Just wrap near and in, and then wrap every other keyword to near (conservatively). So, you're looking at "x (near|in|otherkeywords) y". When I said language processing, I didn't mean it too exactly - but you can use the algos specified if you'd like. Most people will use in, near, around, at.